# HTTP/2 Not working for my resources

Tags: apache2, http2, protocols

I am using Google Cloud Compute Engine running Apache 2.

I enabled HTTP2

```
sudo a2enmod http2
```

I added this to the top of my default-ssl.conf and made it global.

```
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
```

The default-ssl.conf runs properly with all my other commands except protocols.

Then I restarted apache and had zero errors.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

I ran a check and I still get the following:

[image]

All my resources are not running HTTP/2. Is there another step that I am missing?

Comment: Which 11 requests are not served via HTTP/2? Perhaps they are third-party resources from different domains?

Comment: They are all from the same domain and one of them is the domain index itself.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete configuration? What do your logs show?

Comment: I just check the error logs. Says: [Thu Dec 13 10:13:20.150740 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 27291] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are proc$

Comment: Please update your question with relevant information instead of dumping it in a comment.

Comment: Regarding the MPM warning, check: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html